# How to get the code from an Scratch workspace and display with Blockly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mit-scratch, blockly

I'm looking for a way to get the XML (or another way/structure) from a sequence of blocks used on my workspace inside Scratch-MIT 3.0 to display this code in the Blockly Google's library.

Right now I have access to the Abstract Syntax Tree generated by the scratch-vm component (https://github.com/LLK/scratch-vm), but I don't see a way to "rebuild" the code represented on this right on my workspace.

Is Scratch rendering the code from the Abstract Syntax tree structure or what? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new function on my "blocks.jsx" file:

```
onBlockChange() {
    console.log(this.ScratchBlocks.Xml.workspaceToDom(this.workspace));
}
```

And attached a new listener to the VMListener list (also in the "blocks.jsx" file):

```
this.props.vm.addListener('BLOCK_DRAG_UPDATE', this.onBlockChange);
```

This way, everytime that someone add's ou remove a block, I can get the XML info from the workspace.